# Nrwl/Nx jest.preset.js - How to use projectName value in config

Tags: jestjs, nrwl-nx

I have the following `jest.preset.js` in the root of my nx monorepo:

```
const nxPreset = require('@nrwl/jest/preset').default;

module.exports = {
  ...nxPreset,
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/<projectName>',
};
```

This is the preset file for many apps and libs.

I've tried using `<projectName>` to act as the variable to represent the app or lib that the code-coverage is running on, however that doesn't work. Is there a way to reference the actually app/lib that uses this preset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, **jest.preset.js** isn't aware of it's app or lib. so you can't dinamically reference the app/lib's name.

But there's a possible way to workaround.
On your jest.preset.js try this:

```
const placeholder = '__app_or_lib_name__';

const nxPreset = require('@nrwl/jest/preset').default;

module.exports = {
  ...nxPreset,
  coverageDirectory: `../../coverage/${placeholder}`,
};
```

then run:

```
app_or_lib_name=my-app jest
```